# How to use scroll-wheel to change values in Firefox dev-tools, just like in chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, when selecting some value, be it px or %, or pretty much anything, one can use scroll-wheel to change that value (increase/decrease), however, after i switched to Firefox, this, seemingly little thing, bugs me more than i like to admit.

[image]

Since i use that feature literally every day, i would like to be able to do this in Firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

only this great chrome feature force me to use google browser in comparison with firefox

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no changing value with scroll in Firefox, but it's possible to change values with keyboard arrows:

- Up/Down: +-1
- Ctrl + Up/Down: +-0.1
- Shift + Up/Down: +-10
- Shift + PageUp/PageDown: +-100

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts#CSS_pane